# iOS CFBundleIconFiles not showing in summary panel

Tags: ios, xcode, icons, info.plist

My Info.plist file contains this key:

```
<key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
    <array>
        <string>Icon-29</string>
        <string>Icon-120</string>
        <string>Icon-57</string>
        <string>Icon-76</string>
        <string>Icon-40</string>
        <string>Icon-72</string>
    </array>
```

However in the XCode 4 summary panel, it doesn't show my icons.

[image: However in the XCode 4 summary panel, it doesn't show my icons]

When building, I see no warnings. And when running the app in the emulator, the icon seems fine. It just seems strange that it doesn't show in XCode. Any known reason?

Running XCode 4.6.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Retina you should provide Icon-114.

Anyways the one you pasted should be twice in .plist file. One is standalone and second time is under:

```
<key>CFBundleIcons</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
            <array>
                <string>Icon-57px.png</string>
                <string>Icon-114px.png</string>
                <string>Icon-72px.png</string>
                <string>Icon-144px.png</string>
                <string>Default.png</string>
                <string>Default@2x.png</string>
                <string>Default-Landscape~ipad.png</string>
                <string>Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png</string>
            </array>
            <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</key>
```

Make sure it's there as well.

You can also try right-clicking on missing files you showed and use "Select file" to update them - this will configure your plist file as well.